# How to format cells while writing xlsx from python?

Tags: python

I create xlsx-reports via python and would like to do conditional formatting based on the content. In below example I mark the value "123" as bold. Is it possible to set the format of the cell containing "123" to bold?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'aaa': [0, 0, 2, 3],
    'aaBaa': ["0","0","2","\{bold\}123"]
})

j_df = {}
j_df["dummy"] = df.copy()

if 1 == 1:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("dummy.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    for sheet_name, df_write in j_df.items():
        df_write.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
        (max_row, max_col) = df_write.shape
        worksheet.set_column(0,  max_col - 1, 12)
        worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1)
        worksheet.autofit()

        shadedFormat  = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'gray'})
        worksheet.conditional_format('B3:B5', {'format': shadedFormat})


        header_data = df_write.columns.to_list()
        header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True,
                                            'bottom': 2,
                                            'bg_color': '#F9DA04'})

        for col_num, data in enumerate(header_data):
            worksheet.write(0, col_num, data, header_format)
    writer.close()
```